# Async dispatch queue triggering error

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I am trying to code a simple iPhone app that does some modification to file contents in the app sandbox.

I need to make the process lazy. It is also important to ensure serialisation of consecutive file add/modify operation.

I've got this method:

```
   #import "ProcessData.h"
   #import <dispatch/dispatch.h>
   @interface ProcessData ()
   @end

   dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue;
   NSLock *lock;

   @implementation ProcessData
   -(int)newEffects: (int) idNo : (NSString*) someData
   {
    [lock lock];
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void)
     {
      @try
        {
         DiskAccess *dAccess = [[DiskAccess alloc] init];
         //some operations here
         [dAccess release];
         }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
        }
        @finally
        {
            printf("done with this stuff!");
        }
       })
      [lock release];
      }
      @end
```

When I run this code, the application crashes unceremoniously and I get to see this:

```
   0x1b1f2b5:  cmpl   $1, 36(%esi)     Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x24)
```

However, if I change the line:

```
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void)
```

**TO**

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)
```

...the system runs without a hiccup.

I'd like to know:

1. How to get my background queue to work. What am I doing wrong here?
2. If I use **dispatch_get_global_queue** and if there are multiple, back
       to back file access requests, how can I ensure that the operations
       are carried out sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right that you initialize backgroundQueue nowhere? You must initialize backgroundQueue before using it. For example add code

```
    backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create(@"Background queue name", NULL);
```

and only after that call

```
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        //some code here
    });
```

Perhaps a similar error with lock.

Comment: that worked. Thanks a lot.  However, there's no problem with the lock. Lock works as it is.